# Scraping words within a string from websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm pretty new to scrapy and Python. I'm making a web scraper attempting to scrape business owners' names from the HTML text of their websites. My issue is that I can't exactly use an xpath or css response to grab the text from the website code, because I'm scraping hundreds of different websites with different coding, classes, pages, etc. Here's what I have so far:

```
html_text = str(response.text)
owner_name=re.findall("owner", html_text)
    if owner_name:
        print("OWNER FOUND @ " + str(response.url))
```

All this really does, obviously, is let me know if the program has found a page mentioning the owner. I'm not really sure how to go about scraping their name from within the html code. I assume their name would immediately follow wherever owner was mentioned in the HTML, so I'm essentially trying to scrape the next word or two after the word owner.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO please provide minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use strings [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method to get the position of the sub string owner and then [slice](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3) the string.

```py
>>> string = "a lot of filler text and the owner is john doe"
>>> i = string.find("owner")
>>> print(string[i:i+30])
owner is john doe
```